# Devise returns 401 Unauthorized for delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my views i have a link to delete action as below:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', powersaving, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And in my Controller, I have before_filter

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show, :show_details, :destroy]
```

And i tried like this also:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create]
```

In delete action

```
def destroy
    if current_user.admin?
      @powersaving = Powersaving.find(params[:id]) 
      @powersaving.destroy  
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to powersavings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

When i click on the "delete" link it shows "Are you sure?" popup, clicking OK goes to sign_in page of Devise. I need to provide delete action enabled if the current user signed in as "admin". What i am doing wrong?

Comment: In the log message, there is something about the CSRF token when you hit ok on the alert popup?

Comment: It is showing as "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

Answer (score 0):

Add

`<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`

to your `application.html.erb`

Answer (score -1):

The thing is. All HTTP methods except `GET` from your application, must send to the server the CSRF token of authenticity.
One way to avoid this problem is to go in `application_controller.rb` and comment the line `protect_from_forgery`. This is just a way to make it work right now as it is not recommended to leave your app without the CSRF checking.
Later, you can find a way to not check the CSRF token on your links and custom actions without forms.

Comment: No it's not. It doesn't answer the question. You're just removing the part of the application that is causing your issue, you're not fixing the problem. Plus, removing the CSRF check is generally not a good idea.